# Problem deploying my first python app on Streamlit Cloud

Tags: python, streamlit

[GitHub Repo](https://github.com/Eptehal99/end2end-nlp-project)

Link to GitHub repo found above. Everytime I try and deploy the app I get an error about the .pkl file not being in the 'right' directory when in fact the .pkl file is in the same folder as the app.py file. I'm confused and I don't know what else to do.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdIrK.png)

Comment: Welcome to stakoverflow. Please add your code here to the question, formatted as text (use the `{}` button), as a [mcve]. Links can break, or linked content can change (especially on github!), making the question useless for people with similar problems. See also [ask].

Answer (score 1):

In case someone needs the answer, the solution was simple. I realized that my local host had a slightly different repo configuration compared to the GitHub repo. So, I had to adjust for that in the app.py file and then the app was successfully deployed on Streamlit.